# Weird result in bash elif ladder

Tags: linux, bash

**Hi Folks!**

Simple noob bashscript to show diskspace left in the computer.

```
#!/bin/bash

result=$(df --total | tail -n 1)

echo $result

result2=$(echo "$result" | sed -e "s/\s\+/,/g")

echo $result2

result3=$(echo "$result2" | cut -f 5 -d ',')

echo $result3

result4=$(echo "$result3" | tr -d '%')

echo $result4

if [[ $result4 > 50 ]]
then
        echo "WARNING!!! Disk space: ${result4}%"

elif [[ $result4 > 30 ]]
then
        echo "Warning!!! Disk space: ${result4}%"

elif [[ $result4 > 10 ]]
then
        echo "Alert! Disk space: ${result4}%"

elif [[ $result4 > 5 ]]
then
        echo "Is this ok? Disk space: ${result4}%"

elif [[ $result4 > 3 ]]
then
        echo "Disk space: ${result4}%"

else
        echo "Disk space: OK"

fi
```

**Problem/Question**
I *know* that there is less memory used then 10% using:
**df --total** "manualy"
Yet the output of the script when running: *sudo ./nameofscript.sh* keeps returning:

```
Alert! Disk space 2%
```

Can anyone see reason why?

Comment: Use `-gt` for numeric comparisons, `>` is for lexicographic comparison.

Comment: Should I remove the question? Barmar gave correct solution. But I guess more noobs struggle with bash conditionals being, if this then use that if that then use this unless this corner case etc. I seldom find answers since the questions are so specific to a certain conditional problem so I can seldom apply it to mine. Thanks for the help @Barmar

Comment: You could if you want, but there's no need.